# how to close all the opened windows(except the parent)onclick from a parent window in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a parent window which calls for a function that opens 2 new windows in javascript.
When I click a close button, I want to close both the child windows.
I tried window.close(windowname); windowName.close(). Both didn't work.

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

Assign the return values of your `window.open(...)` calls and call `.close()` on them later.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/NCzvH/1/

Comment: You might want to change that to `if (windows[i]&&!windows[i].closed) windows[i].close();`

Comment: At least the first one will be always true since it cannot be removed from that list unless you write code for it. The other one ok.. but it doesn't seem to throw an error when trying to close the already-closed window.

Comment: It will be null if the window did not open, unless push cannot push a null

Comment: Indeed, didn't think about popup blockers